# SQL Query to XML with tag attributes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

There is a table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp
    (ID int, name varchar(50));

INSERT INTO temp
    ([ID], [name])
VALUES
    (1, 'Value 1'),
    (2, 'Value 2');
```

Need SQL query returning the following result:

```
<root>
 <row>
  <param name="first">1</param>
  <param name="second">Value 1</param>
 </row>
 <row>
  <param name="first">2</param>
  <param name="second">Value 2</param>
 </row>
</root>
```

Estimated Query is:

```
SELECT
  [ID] as [param/@name['first']],
  [name] as [param/@name['second']]
FROM
  temp
for xml path('row'), root('root')
```

Please correct Query to make it work.

Comment: The second `<row>` fragment is completely different from the first `<row>` fragment. Are you sure about it?

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky Thanks! Corrected

Comment: If the suggested solution is working for you please mark it as correct (the green check image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*XQuery FLWOR* expression gives you a full control on the shape of the XML. Check it out:

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT PRIMARY KEY, [name] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @tbl (id, [name])
VALUES (1, 'Value 1')
    , (2, 'Value 2');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs(xml_data) AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH('row'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
)
SELECT xml_data.query('<root>
{ 
    for $r in /root/row
    return 
    <row>
        <param name="first">{data($r/id/text())}</param>
        <param name="second">{data($r/name/text())}</param>
    </row>
}
</root>') AS xml_output
FROM rs;
```

> Output

```
<root>
  <row>
    <param name="first">1</param>
    <param name="second">Value 1</param>
  </row>
  <row>
    <param name="first">2</param>
    <param name="second">Value 2</param>
  </row>
</root>
```

Comment: exactly what is needed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yitzhak, I think, this can be put simpler... I just placed an answer myself...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach might be this:

```
SELECT  'first' as [param/@name]
        ,ID as [param]
        ,''
        ,'second' as [param/@name]
        ,[name] as [param] 
FROM temp t
FOR XML PATH('row'), root('root');
```

The idea in short:

The engine works down the columns and finds

- We have to open a `<root>`
- We have to open a `<row>` for each row of the set
- Okay, the first column is a new element `<param>`, we have to open it.
- Now the value ("first") has to be written as an attribute `@name`.
- The next value (`ID`) is also living in `<param>`, which is still open. Add it as a `text()` node.
- Well the next column is - uhm - empty??? However... First we must close the open `<param>`...
- Okay, the next column looks better. There is an element `<param>`... Okay, the last one is closed, we have to open a new one!
- and so on...

This also works with fragments of paths:

```
SELECT  'first' as [param/onemore/@name]
        ,ID as [param/onemore]
        ,'' AS [param]
        ,'second' as [param/onemore/@name]
        ,[name] as [param/onemore] 
FROM temp t
FOR XML PATH('row'), root('root');
```

The result

```
<root>
  <row>
    <param>
      <onemore name="first">1</onemore>
      <onemore name="second">Value 1</onemore>
    </param>
  </row>
  <row>
    <param>
      <onemore name="first">2</onemore>
      <onemore name="second">Value 2</onemore>
    </param>
  </row>
</root>
```

In this case we re-open `<onemore>`, but we stay within the open `<param>`.

Comment: Strange, I tried same query from beginning of your answer and it didn't work... so I came up w/ subquery. :)

Comment: Great answer, +1 from my side! Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with sub-queries:

```
SELECT  'first' as [param/@name],
        ID as [param],
        (SELECT 'second' as [param/@name], 
                name as [param] 
        FROM temp t1 WHERE t1.ID = t.ID 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE )  
FROM temp t
FOR XML PATH('row'), root('root')
```

Output:

```
<root>
  <row>
    <param name="first">1</param>
    <param name="second">Value 1</param>
  </row>
  <row>
    <param name="first">2</param>
    <param name="second">Value 2</param>
  </row>
</root>
```

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side! It is always nice to have a second solution.

Comment: This can be done simpler, I just placed an answer, might be interesting for you...